# How can I make my terminal experience more visually pleasing on Fedora 37 for reading manpages?

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora, manpages

I currently use the basic GNOME Terminal on Fedora and I've had to do a lot of reading of manpages in it lately and would prefer a more visually appealing experience beyond simply changing background/foreground colors and transparency. Is there a way for me to add for example a background image, font or background gradients, or otherwise add a bit more contrast to the manpages to beautify them a bit?

Answer (score 0):

try [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat#man)

> bat can be used as a colorizing pager for man, by setting the MANPAGER environment variable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).